# Memory Leak related to setImage

Tags: ios, memory, uiimage, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak which crashes the app. When i comment line above, i don't have any memory leak.

> myCell.image1.image = image;

myCell is a custom **UICollectionViewCell** and created as:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CustomCollectionCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"project" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_images[row] options:0 error:NULL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    myCell.image1.image = image;
    return myCell;
}
```

The image is about 8 MB and there are 7 images. When I open the view controller for the forth time, the app crashes (8x7x4 > 200 MB) ;)

**CustomCollectionCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CellButton.h"

@interface CustomCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titlePro;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *datePro;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CellButton * button;

@end
```

**CustomCollectionCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCollectionCell.h"
#import "UIView+Themes.h"

@implementation CustomCollectionCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

I profiled and Live Bytes get higher than 200 MB, and the app crashes without errors. When i comment the `myCell.image1.image = image;`. The app doesn't crash.

I'm using ARC.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: we need more code than that to help you. Where is `myCell` created? Is it a custom class? How are you declaring image1 and image? Are you using ARC?

Comment: @LuisCien i uptated my question, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that's the declaration of `image1`? IBOutlet is not a type. It should be declared something like: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *image1`

Comment: @LuisCien sorry, i updated my question again, i don't have internet connection on my other computer, so i type all code

Comment: Oh, and BTW, what does the crash log says?

Comment: How big are the images that are displayed? How big are the image files that you are displaying? How many images are being displayed at once?

Comment: @LuisCien i don't have any crash logs. i update my question one more time ;)

Comment: I ask, because I don't want to assume that you are just loading thumbnail sized images.

Comment: @Abizern The image is about 8 MB and there are 7 images. When I open the view controller for the forth time, the app crashes (8x7x4 > 200 MB) ;)

Comment: So you aren't loading thumbnail sized images then. That's the first thing you should be fixing because loading 7 x 8mb files at once is a bad sign.

Comment: And how are you configuring your cells for the collection view?

Comment: @Abizern you're right but i want to know why the images are not released.

Comment: Have you tried running the app through the Allocations instrument? Take snapshots as you load the controller, and then see where the images are being allocated.

Comment: @Abizern i configure them in cellForItemAtIndePath if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Could you post your full implementation of it? Also your `prepareForReuse` implementation.

Comment: Doesn't make it any clearer. Sorry. Short of actually debugging it myself. But, try my Allocations Instrument suggestion. Also look at using an image cache for your images rather than reloading them from file each time, and use resized thumbnails rather than cramming the full image into a small image view. Also set all visible image view images to nil when they are not on screen when you get a memory warning.

Comment: post the .h and .m files for CustomCollectionCell please

Comment: @NickGalasso i posted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller that contains CustomCollectionCell had a modal segue and i never called the line below.

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

That was why my images were not released.